# What is the difference between a private static function vs. a public static function in typescript?

Tags: class, angular, typescript, static

In the context of an angular2 service; what is the difference between a private static function vs. a public static function in typescript?

```
  public static getUserStockList(): Stock[] {
    /* TODO: implement http call */
    return WATCHLIST;
  }
```

vs.

```
  private static getUserStockList(): Stock[] {
    /* TODO: implement http call */
    return WATCHLIST;
  }
```

**EDIT:**

When would it be appropriate to use a private static function over a private function?

Comment: Hi i think the difference is the scope of the Funciton ..so the public is visible also outside your class (for example if you did it in a service) .. the private no .. is only visible in the class itself

Comment: The same with any other OO languages, `private` is only visible to the instance of the class itself, `protected` is only visible to the instance of the class and extending classes, and `public` is visible to all

Comment: @NitzanTomer static methods are members on the class though so they can't be invoked by any instance of the class. So what's the difference between public and private static methods? Does it mean other classes can invoke those static class methods vs private static only being able to invoke within the defined class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private static methods can be invoked from instances of the class.
An example of this:

```
interface Data {
    // ...
}

interface StrictData {
    // ...

abstract class MyClass {
    protected constructor(data: StrictData) {
        // ...
    }
}

class AnotherClass extends MyClass {
    private static normalizeData(data?: Data | StrictData): StrictData {
        // ...
    }

    constructor(data?: Data | StrictData) {
        super(AnotherClass.normalizeData(data));
    }
}
```

`AnotherClass.normalizeData` is accessible from the instance and the compiler is just fine with this.
However, this:

```
console.log(AnotherClass.normalizeData({}));
```

Will result in:

> Property 'normalizeData' is private and only accessible within class
>   'AnotherClass'